# Can the short-time dynamics of an open quantum system be approximately unitary?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, research-level

Considering the physics of an open quantum system described by a Hamiltonian

$H=H_S+H_E+H_{SE}$,

where the subscript $S$ refers to the system of interest, $E$ to the environment and $SE$ to the interaction between them,

It is possible that at short-times and for sufficiently weak system-environment coupling, the evolution of the system of interest is approximately unitary?

If yes, what defines the time-scale of unitarity?
Does the Hamiltonian that describes the short time evolution is $H_S$ or some renormalized Hamiltonian?

Finally, is there any relation between my question and the phenomenom of decoherence?

Comment: It seems that right now, your Hamiltonian describes the entire system (including the environment), so there would just be unitary evolution.

Comment: I am interested only in the dynamics of the subsystem $S$, the "system of interest".

Comment: how do you measure deviations from unitarity? what is the metric?